# Using a Github Actions Version as a value in Composite Action

Tags: github, continuous-integration, version, github-actions

I have created a custom composite action that has a step that pulls files from a repository during its run using the following.

```
- uses: robinraju/release-downloader@v1.5
      with:
        repository: "ORG/REPONAME"
        tag: "v0.0.1"
        tarBall: true
        out-file-path: "FILENAME"
        token: ${{ steps.auth.outputs.token }}
```

I need the `tag` param to be dynamic and match the version number the user sets when calling my composite action. For example a user sets the following in their workflow `.github/workflows/FILE.yaml` file

```
jobs:
  run-my-action:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: ORG/my-custom-action@v0.0.2
```

The action will run and during its run read/inject my actions version from `ORG/my-custom-action@v0.0.2` then use the version number stated `v0.0.2` as the version number for one of its steps within its composition

```
- uses: robinraju/release-downloader@v1.5
      with:
        repository: "ORG/REPONAME"
        tag: ${{ ACTION_VERSION }}
```

Rather not have to set another input for my action to take in a version. When the action version will be the same as the version number the step needs

Comment: Can you use `github.action_ref` from the [`github` context](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context)?

Comment: that would work if the workflow existed within the repo my action was in. However other workflows will be calling this action within their respective repos